# Adding a FileField to a custom SignupForm with django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth, django-1.8

I have the following custom SignupForm (simplified, works perfectly without my_file):

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    home_phone = forms.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15)
    my_file = forms.FileField()

    def signup(self, request, user):
        new_user = ReqInfo(
            user=user,
            home_phone=self.cleaned_data['home_phone'],
            my_file=my_file,
        )
        new_user.save()
```

In models.py:

```
class ReqInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    home_phone = models.CharField(
        validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15)
    my_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/directory/', validators=[resume_file_validator], blank=True, null=True)
```

My issue:

When I add a a user in myurl/accounts/signup it tells me that the my_file field is Required, even though I select a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signup.html template allauth uses did not have

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

After adding it, it works like a charm.

Comment: How did you add the enctype attr to the default template?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Django signals to create a `post_save` signal to intimate when a new user is being saved to the `User` model.
When signalled, you can create your `ReqInfo` instance and save it.

- Override the User model given by Django to include 2 new fields, `file_input` and `home_phone`.
- Override the allauth `SignupForm` to include a `Filefield` for your file input and a CharField for your `home_phone` field.
- Don't forget to import your signals file into the ready function of your `AppConfig` in `apps.py`, or else your signals wont work!

But this method requires the Default Django User model be modified.