# django-allauth Custom signup form. How to add a field with image uploadI(image field)?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using Django and Allauth. I need the user to be able to upload photos when registering. At the moment form works, but the selected photo does not load

Models.py:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
bdate = models.DateField( blank=True, null=True, default="1990-01-01")
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='accounts/', blank=True, null=True, default=""  )
phone = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=""  )

def __str__(self):
    return "%s, %s" % (self.username, self.first_name)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Пользователя'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'
```

Adapter.py

```
class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
    data = form.cleaned_data
    user.username = data.get('username')
    user.email = data['email']
    user.first_name = data['first_name']
    user.last_name = data['last_name']
    user.bdate = data['bdate']
    user.photo = data['photo']
    user.phone = data['phone']
    if 'password1' in data:
        user.set_password(data['password1'])
    else:
        user.set_unusable_password()
    self.populate_username(request, user)
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Forms.py

```
class SignupForm (forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={"class": "input_text", }), required=True,)
username = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={"class": "input_text", }), required=True,)
password1 = SetPasswordField()
password2 = PasswordField()
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={"class": "input_text", }), required=True,)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={"class": "input_text", }), required=True,)
bdate = forms.DateField( widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={"id": "date", "type": "date" }), required=True, )
phone = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={"class": "input_text",  }) , required=True,)
photo = forms.ImageField(required=False,)

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    exclude = [" "]


def signup(self, request, user):
    user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.bdate = self.cleaned_data['bdate']
    user.photo = self.cleaned_data['photo']
    user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
    user.save()
```

I have of course specified ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS in settings.py to point to this form and it displays the fields which I've put in it.
In the settings I installed :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'lk.Profile'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'cabin.forms.SignupForm'
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'lk.adapter.AccountAdapter'
```

How do I get the image to be uploaded to the server when user register?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: image does not load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signup.html template allauth uses didnt have

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Solution found here: [Adding a FileField to a custom SignupForm with django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376019/adding-a-filefield-to-a-custom-signupform-with-django-allauth)